# jQuery AJAX type jsonp, returning malformed JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
$('#rn_s').keyup(function() {
    var rn = $('#rn_s').val();

    if(rn.length == 9) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://routingnumbers.info/api/data.json?rn=' + rn,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp', 
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And it returns this:

`Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain`

And then returned content is `Object {}`

How can I access these values?

Comment: Why are you using jsonp as the data type instead of json?

Comment: Looks like that's what the API requires.

Comment: *"How can I access these values?"* Like you would for any object

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Ysf8x/

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working okay for me. I created a fiddle, using chrome and the latest version of jQuery (not v2).

This is basically what you had, minus the keyUp events:

```
var rn = 122242597;

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://routingnumbers.info/api/data.json?rn=' + rn,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('#customerName').text(result.customer_name);
        $('#address').text(result.address);
        $('#zipCode').text(result.zip);
    } });
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<div>
    <span id="customerName"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <span id="address"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <span id="zipCode"></span>
</div>
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ysf8x/1/) for a working example. Obviously your HTML will differ, but accessing the returned properties and assigning them to your UI should be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at that API's documentation? That call returns a `json` object.

http://www.routingnumbers.info/api/data.html

To access the values, look at the API documentation for the value names. For example, to get the address of the result:

`var address = result.address`

Comment: This is a public API. To get around the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" limitation, the JSONP data type is required for it to work correctly. The callback is there so that if you are doing a manual creation of a script element, you can specify which callback is going to process the data. By specifiying 'JSONP' as the dataType in the jQuery ajax function, it handles all that stuff for you.

Comment: @JoshTaylor Way ahead of you, I already edited my answer when I looked at it